# How would you solve this GPS/location problem and scale it? Would you use a Database? R-tree?

Tags: python, mysql, database, computer-science

Suppose I have a people and their GPS coordinates:

```
User1, 52.99, -41.0
User2, 91.44, -21.4
User3, 5.12, 24.5
...
```

**My objective is:
Given a set of coordinates,**

1. Out of all those users, find the ones within 20 meters. (how to do a SELECT statement like this?)
2. For each of those users, get the distance.

As you probably guessed, these coordinates will be retrieved from a mobile phone.  The phones will update their longitude/latitude every 10 seconds, as well as get that list of  users <20 meters.  It's dynamic.

I would like the best way to do this so that it can scale.

- Would you store the coordinates in a database, and update it every 10
  seconds? (If you store it in a database...how would you calculate it...)
- How would you do this so it can scale?

By the way, there is already a formula that can calculate the distance between 2 coordinates http://www.johndcook.com/python_longitude_latitude.html. I just need to know what's the best way to do this technically **(Trees, Database? What architecture? More specifically...how would you tie in the long/lat distance formula into the "SELECT" statement?)**

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a `MyISAM` table with a column of datatype `Point`
2. Create a `SPATIAL` index on this column
3. Convert the `GPS` coords into `UTM` (grid) coords and store them in your table
4. Issue this query:

   ```
   SELECT  user_id, GLength(LineString(user_point, @mypoint))
   FROM    users
   WHERE   MBRWithin(user_point, LineString(Point(X(@mypoint) - 20, Y(@mypoint - 20)), Point(X(@mypoint) + 20, Y(@mypoint + 20))
           AND GLength(LineString(user_point, @mypoint)) <= 20
   ```

Note that this query will most probably be run on very volatile data and you will need to do the additional checks on time.

Since `MySQL` cannot combine `SPATIAL` indexes, it will be better to use some kind of surface tiling technology:

1. Split the Earth surface into a number of tiles, say, `1 x 1 "` (it's about `30` meters of the meridian and `30 * COS(lon)` of the parallel.
2. Store the data in the `CHAR(14)` column: `7` digits of the `lat` + `7` digits on the `lon` (14 digits at all). Disable key compression on this column.
3. Create a composite index on `(time, tile)`
4. **On the client**, calculate all possible tiles your mates *may* be in. For `20` meters distance, this will be at most `9` tiles, unless you are deep at North or South. However, you may change the tiling algorithm to handle these cases.
5. Issue this query:

   ```
   SELECT  *
   FROM    (
           SELECT  tile1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT  tile2
           UNION ALL
           …
           ) tiles
   JOIN    users u
   ON      u.tile  = tiles.tile
           AND u.time >= NOW() 
           AND GLength(LineString(user_point, @mypoint)) <= 20
   ```

, where `tile1` etc are precalculated tiles.

`SQL Server` implements this algorithm for its spatial indexes (rather than `R-Tree` that `MySQL` uses).

Comment: Quassnoi...did you write that formula yourself? Or is it pretty standard? (the select where... formula)

Comment: @alex: I wrote the formula myself using the standard `MySQL` geomery functions: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/geometry-property-functions.html Note that these functions require a Euclidean plane, hence the requirement to store in `UTM`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the naive approach would be to do an *O(n)* pass over all points, get their distance from the current point, and find the top 20. This is perfectly Ok for small datasets (say <= 500 points), but on larger sets it's going to be quite slow. In SQL, this would be along the lines of:

```
SELECT point_id, DIST_FORMULA(x, y) as distance
FROM   points
WHERE  distance < 20
```

To address the inefficiency of the above method, you would have to use some sort of preprocessing step, most likely [space partitioning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_partitioning). That can often dramatically improve performance in nearest neighbour type of searches like this. However, in your case, if all the points are updated every 10 seconds, you would have to do an *Ω(n)* pass to update the position of each point in the space partitioning tree. If you have more than a few queries between each update, it will be useful, otherwise it'll simply be an overhead.

Answer (score 0):

[Chapter 11](http://my.safaribooksonline.com/9780123746306/chapter_11_modeling_and_queryi) "Database Design Know it All" has some thoughts on how to design such a database.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out if I ever get a user/pass :)